# No report from backup.sh to mail

Tags: server, backup, email, postfix

I have a problem with the backup report in Ubuntu Server 16.04. In `/usr/local/bin` I have `backup.sh` and for some time I do not get a report from this script to mail.
In `/var/mail/nobody` I see that emails try to send but there is a message:

```
<admin@mymail.com>: host mymail.com [XXX.XXX.XX.XX] said: 550 5.7.1 Client host rejected: can not find your hostname (in reply to RCPT TO command).
```

When I type 
`hostname -f`,
Ubuntu returns "server". In `/etc/hostname` I have "server".
I can not find the script responsible for sending the report. In `backup.sh` it is not ... Maybe someone can direct me ...
In `main.cf` (postfix) I have:

```
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = server
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = server.myname.pl, $myhostname, server, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.14.0/24
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
inet_protocols = all
```

One more thing...
If I issue the command

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" me@emydomain.pl
```

In /var/mail/nobody I have

```
From MAILER-DAEMON  Thu Mar 28 07:06:26 2019
Return-Path: <>
X-Original-To: root@server.mydomain.pl
Delivered-To: root@server.mydomain.pl
Received: by server (Postfix)
        id 4CE0E10085C; Thu, 28 Mar 2019 07:06:26 +0100 (CET)
Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 07:06:26 +0100 (CET)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@server.mydomain.pl (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: root@server.mydomain.pl
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="14AB0100854.1553753186/server"
Message-Id: <20190328060626.4CE0E10085C@server>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.
--14AB0100854.1553753186/server
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

This is the mail system at host server.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<me@mydomain.pl>: host mydomain.pl[XX.XX.XX.X] said: 550 5.7.1 Client
    host rejected: cannot find your hostname (in reply to RCPT TO command)

--14AB0100854.1553753186/server
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; server
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 14AB0100854
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; root@server.mydomain.pl
Arrival-Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 07:06:25 +0100 (CET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; me@mydomain.pl
Original-Recipient: rfc822;me@mydomain.pl
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; mydomain.pl
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your
    hostname

--14AB0100854.1553753186/server
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <root@server.mydomain.pl>
Received: by server (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id 14AB0100854; Thu, 28 Mar 2019 07:06:26 +0100 (CET)
To: me@mydomain.pl
Subject: This is the subject line
Message-Id: <20190328060626.14AB0100854@server>
Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 07:06:25 +0100 (CET)
From: root@server.mydomain.pl (root)

This is the body of the email

--14AB0100854.1553753186/server--
```

Comment: hello. what is your situation, are you a company employee or a private individual? are you referencing one or serveral machines in this question, E.G. only the one screen you are sitting in front of or is there another machine/server involved? if so how is it connected to your personal computer? what is the procedure you describe? and what is it supposed to do? where did this script you are using come from? are you at liberty to share it's contents? if so, please paste it's contents and format it as code in your original post. please provide any other bit of aditional context that is googlable

Comment: Likely the script is being scheduled via a `crontab` and it is `cron` that is responsible for mailing its output

Comment: @tatsu I'm a private person. I am referring to one device connected in a lan network. I connect to the device through putty. the script comes from usr / local / bin on the server. until March 13, every day I received an e-mail with a report about the execution of the baskup.sh scripts. Then the mail stopped coming. the sender of the e-mails was Cron Daemon <root @ server> and the recipient of my e-mail. It should not have an impact because it does not send from it.
The backup.sh file executes properly because the backup is done. Only the report is missing ...

Comment: private person or not, we can't help you if you give 0 information

Comment: @j-money Thank you very much.
The question concerned the possible location of a file that can send a report ... For this, the backup.sh content is not needed ...

Comment: check if mail server is running, if running check if IP is accessible, if accessible send an email to yourself manually as cron is sending, if you receive then check cron if it's running your cron task, if not running check your cron logs, if still you didn't get that resolved, please update your question with details suggested you to do and the result you get from each step.

Comment: in the file / var / mail / nobody I see that emails try to send but there is a message
<admin@mymail.com>: host mymail.com [my ip] said: 550 5.7.1 Client
     host rejected: can not find your hostname (in reply to RCPT TO command)

Answer (score 0):

As the information you posted is very vague, I can only post a vague answer:

You have something somewhere that was sending you mail, but you don't know what.  Now you get a response:

```
host mydomain.pl[XX.XX.XX.X] said: 550 5.7.1 Client
host rejected: cannot find your hostname (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

The above means that the server who was sending your mail is not accepting your hostname any more.

Contact the mail administrator of said mail server and have them verify why. (They might have gone commercial, were an open mail relay and are not any more, ...)